# Could not find version matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0)

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo

I am using expo - expokit( react-native) to develop my app. Don't know why it failed when build app.
I have checked the the same error on Stack overflow but none of them is solved my problem

Here is the error.

```
org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:74)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.0, 16.0.0).
Required by:
    project :app > com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.1.1
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver.resolve(DynamicVersionResolver.java:122)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainDependencyToComponentIdResolver.resolve(RepositoryChainDependencyToComponentIdResolver.java:72)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.ComponentResolversChain$DependencyToComponentIdResolverChain.resolve(ComponentResolversChain.java:150)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.SelectorState.resolve(SelectorState.java:170)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.selectors.SelectorStateResolver.buildResolveResults(SelectorStateResolver.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.selectors.SelectorStateResolver.resolveSelectors(SelectorStateResolver.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.selectors.SelectorStateResolver.selectBest(SelectorStateResolver.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.performSelection(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:232)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.performSelectionSerially(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:213)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolveEdges(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.traverseGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:155)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:126)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:167)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.java:89)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$5.run(DefaultConfiguration.java:533)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:524)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveToStateOrLater(DefaultConfiguration.java:509)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1800(DefaultConfiguration.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationTaskDependency.visitDependencies(DefaultConfiguration.java:1514)
    ... 96 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.listModuleVersions(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:126)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver$VersionListResult.process(DynamicVersionResolver.java:536)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver$VersionListResult.resolve(DynamicVersionResolver.java:521)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver$RepositoryResolveState.resolve(DynamicVersionResolver.java:290)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver.findLatestModule(DynamicVersionResolver.java:177)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver.findLatestModule(DynamicVersionResolver.java:169)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver.resolve(DynamicVersionResolver.java:111)
    ... 121 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/maven-metadata.xml.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.maven.MavenMetadataLoader.load(MavenMetadataLoader.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.maven.MavenVersionLister.listVersions(MavenVersionLister.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.metadata.DefaultMavenPomMetadataSource.listModuleVersions(DefaultMavenPomMetadataSource.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.doListModuleVersions(ExternalResourceResolver.java:210)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.access$200(ExternalResourceResolver.java:90)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$RemoteRepositoryAccess.listModuleVersions(ExternalResourceResolver.java:440)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$ResolveAndCacheRepositoryAccess.listModuleVersions(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:360)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.listModuleVersions(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:121)
    ... 127 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/maven-metadata.xml'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.failure(ResourceExceptions.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.getFailed(ResourceExceptions.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.copyToCache(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:201)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/maven-metadata.xml'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:96)
    ... 157 more
```

Here is the app/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com'}
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'
    classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.1, 0.99.99]'
  }

defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.youmed.info'
    minSdkVersion safeExtGet("minSdkVersion", 21)
    targetSdkVersion safeExtGet("targetSdkVersion", 28)
    versionCode 13
    versionName '1.2.2'
    multiDexEnabled true
  }
dependencies {

  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
  implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0"
}
.....
// This has to be down here for some reason
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

Here is the project/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
  ext {
    minSdkVersion = 21
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.0'
    supportLibVersion = '28.0.0'
    kotlinVersion = '1.3.21'
  }
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
  }
}
allprojects {
  repositories {
google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com'}
}
}
```

Anyone know How to solve this problem

Comment: I had this problem and i have  appled solution